# Change an attribute name in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Say I have a networkx graph with some nodes and some edges, with attributes "foo" and "bar" on each edge. I'd like to be able to change the name of the attribute "foo" to be "baz", preferably without iterating through the entire edge list.

Ideal code would be something like:

```
g.rename_edge_attr(from="foo", to="baz")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why dont you try and share the result with us?

Comment: Hi balderman. If you would like the output of the code snippet above: `AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'rename_edge_attr'` My apologies if it wasn't clear that this is pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by directly manipulating the dictionary of data associated with each edge:

```
for u, v, data in G.edges(data=True):
    data["baz"] = data.pop("foo")
```

Comment: I'm dealing with large graphs so I'd prefer not to have to iterate through the entire edge list. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: There is one data dictionary per edge. You cannot change an attribute name in `n` dictionaries in less than `Theta(n)` time. The only workaround would be to write some wrapper logic (e.g. override `__getitem__`) which returns `data["foo"]` every time someone tries to access `data["baz"]`. The underlying data will be unchanged, but you can control access (though it will make accessing a bit slower).

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not delete the old attribute, but simply creates a new one:

```
w = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'foo')
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, w, 'baz')
```

I am not sure about performance, though.